# Can PortalVue be used across several Vue.js single file components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Currently I'm working on Vue.js (single file components) and found three ways to pass data around: local state/props, store and [PortalVue](https://markus.oberlehner.net/images/2018-05-27/should-i-store-this-data-in-vuex-flow-chart.png). During my experiment with PortalVue, my only success was implementing both **portal** and **portal-target** within one same .vue file, while attempts using **portal** and **portal-target** across two .vue files did not work.

It was stated in PortalVue [documentation](https://linusborg.github.io/portal-vue/#/guide) that "*PortalVue is a set of two components that allow you to render a component's template (or a part of it) anywhere in the document - even outside the part controlled by your Vue App!*"

Does that means PortalVue only work when both portal components reside in same file?

**It works within one component**

ComponentA.vue:

```
<portal to="destination">
  <p>Send this to destination</p>
</portal>

<portal-target name="destination">
</portal-target>
```

**While this doesn't render**

ComponentA.vue:

```
<portal to="destination">
  <p>Send this to destination</p>
</portal>
```

ComponentB.vue:

```
<portal-target name="destination">
</portal-target>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works across multiple components.  I think what you're missing is that the components have to **both** be rendered on the page at the same time for you to see the portal.

```js
Vue.component('foo', {
 template: '#foo',  
});

Vue.component('bar', {
 template: '#bar',  
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/portal-vue@1.5.1/dist/portal-vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <foo></foo>
  <bar></bar>
</div>

<template id="foo">
  <div class="wrapper">
    Foo
    <portal to="destination">This is from foo</portal>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="bar">
  <div class="wrapper">
    Bar
    <portal-target name="destination"></portal-target>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks! Initially I used the portal in components that were loaded in different pages. I can see it working now by doing what you said and it's rendered when both components are loaded on same page.